# How To Reduce Database Size

Tags: database, ms-access-2010, filesize

So I've had a database for some time now, accumulated some 20 tables with a variety of records per table.

I've since made a copy of the database and pretty much gutted everything except one table, with 5 records currently.

Then I happened to notice the file sizes. I assumed by removing a ton of unless information my database size would be reduced, however it stayed the same.

Why is that? Can the size be reduced somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `File` menu, select `Info`, then click the `Compact & Repair Database` button.

Comment: Good to know. Sorry, seems relatively easy to accomplish and overlooked this. Thanks!

Comment: Slight issue, when I do this, it says could not use <<filename>>; file already in use. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Nevermind, must've been something with using the database via my Google Drive. I copied down to my desktop and the compact and repair worked.